# Angular - Mapping form value with array value

Tags: html, arrays, angular, select

I have an array:

`myArray = [ "Confirmed / Unconfirmed", "In / Out" ]`

I have a HTML Select

```
<select formControlName="choice_type">
   <option></option>
   <option *ngFor="let choice of myArray" [value]="choice"> {{ choice }} </option>
</select>
```

However, my form is updated with values from a database. In the database, the value for the choice is `choice_confirmed_unconfirmed` or `choice_in_out`.

Is it possible that when i patch my angular form that the HTML select will display a value from the array that matches the returned value from the database?

For example, if the form value returns as `choice_in_out`, then the select dropdown will be preselected with `In / Out`?

Is there a way to bind the database format for those values with how I want them to display in the drop down?

Comment: Can you not have your array like an array of mappings?

Comment: Hey @AshishRanjan it sounds like what I'm after. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a mapping object instead of an array and have strings mapped with what you want to display, while keeping the value same as you get from DB.

```
myArray = {
     choice_confirmed_unconfirmed: "Confirmed / Unconfirmed"
     choice_in_out: "In / Out"
}

<option *ngFor="let choice of myArray | keyvalue" [value]="choice.key"> 
   {{ choice.value }}
</option>
```

Comment: It's bizarre, I tried that and it didn't work first time, must have missed something. Anyway, copying yours worked! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Haven No problem, it happens